# Wrapper ignore hidden divs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, hidden

I'm using this small wrapper plugin:

https://github.com/tsevdos/nwrapper

```
(function($) {

$.fn.nwrapper = function(options){

    var defaults = {
        wrapEvery : 1,
        defaultClasses : true,
        extraClasses : false,
        htmlStructure : 'div'
    };

    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var elements = $(this).children();
    var elementsLen = elements.length;

    for ( var i = 0, numb = 1; i < elementsLen; i += settings.wrapEvery, numb++ ){

        // Default Classes Array
        var classes = [];
        if ( settings.defaultClasses ) {

            classes[0] = 'wrapper';
            classes[1] = 'wrapper-' + numb;

            if (numb==1) {
                classes[2] = 'first';
            }

            if (numb==Math.ceil(elementsLen/settings.wrapEvery)) {
                classes[2] = 'last';
            }

        }

        // Merge Default class with Extra Class
        if ( settings.extraClasses ) {
            $.merge( classes, settings.extraClasses );
        }

        // If you find any classes crete the class string
        if ( classes.length > 0 ) {
            htmlClassesString = 'class="' + classes.join(" ") + '"';
        } else {
            htmlClassesString = '';
        }

        elements.filter(':eq(' + i + '), :lt(' + (i + settings.wrapEvery) + '):gt(' + i + ')').wrapAll('<' + settings.htmlStructure + ' ' + htmlClassesString + ' />');

    }

    return $(this);
};

})(jQuery);
```

Basic layout would be:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="filter1">Value</div>
   <div class="filter2">Value</div> 
   <div class="filter3">Value</div> 
   <div class="filter1">Value</div> 
   <div class="filter2">Value</div> 
   <div class="filter3">Value</div>
   <div class="filter1">Value</div> 
   <div class="filter2">Value</div> 
   <div class="filter3">Value</div>  
   ... 
</div>
```

Initializing plugin:

```
$('#container').nwrapper({ wrapEvery : 3 });
```

I use select filters which hide/show children divs and then reinitialize the plugin. I was wondering would it be possible to exclude hidden divs from the wrap count?

Finally I use jQuery cycle to display the wrapped divs, so hidden divs should be inside wraps (but not counted). Otherwise cycle will treat each hidden div as an item.

Perhaps this plugin is not the optimal tool for what I'm trying to achieve. It will produce following:

I want wrap every three visible divs, but also include hidden ones.

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-1 first">
    <div class="filter1">Value</div>
    <div class="filter2">Value</div>
    <div class="filter3" style="display:none;">Value</div>
    <div class="filter1">Value</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-2 last">
    <div class="filter2">Value</div>
    <div class="filter3" style="display:none;">Value</div>
    <div class="filter1">Value</div>
    <div class="filter2">Value</div>
    <div class="filter3" style="display:none;">Value</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `:visible` selector, although I'm not sure how well it works on IE.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the plugin accrodingly. like

Replace this :

```
var elements = $(this).children();
```

With

```
var elements = $(this).children(":visible");
```

=====================================================================

@teeraina, In terms of your problem "I would need the hidden divs be included inside the wrap divs (but not counted)" You could try this :

```
var elements = $(this).children();
var elementsLen = $(this).children(":visible").length;
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Yes. This works. Problem is that I use jquery cycle to display the wrapped divs. I would need the hidden divs be included inside the wrap divs (but not counted). Otherwise cycle will include each hidden div as an item.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it still leaves hidden divs out and lists them after wrap divs.

Comment: @teeraina, can you provide exact code with cycle plugin as well ?

Comment: The cycle plugin will work fine, if I can achieve the desired html structure with the wrap. See my updated explanation above.